# Valid way to determine effect of binary independent variable on dependent variable

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, model, effect-size

TLDR; Given a set of highly correlated variables, what would be a valid way to determine the effect of one of the independent (binary) variables?

I have a dataset (very high data quality, circa 100k observations) and have built a logistic regression model to predict a binary dependent variable. The independent variables are categorical or binary.

Unfortunately, there is a reasonable degree of correlation between the independent variables and the dependent variable. There's about a 50/50 split for 0 and 1 for the dependent variable.

Would a valid approach to determine the effect of one of the binary independent variables (80% 0; 20% 1) be:

- to build a model on the entire dataset (having split to a train / test / validate data sets first);
- use this model to predict the dependent variable for the 20% of the population who had a 1, but pretend that they were a 0;
- compare the result to the observed dependent variable likelihood